# Turn parsed corpus into data frame using stringr and regex

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I'm trying to transform a parsed corpus into a data frame in R using stringr and regular expressions (I've since read that maybe I shouldn't be using regular expressions for this kind of work, but I spent so much time on this I would like to know whether there is a solution). The corpus looks like this:

```
text <- paste("<w type=\"NP0\" lemma=\"dorothy\">Dorothy</w><c type=\"PUN\">, </c><w type=\"PRP\" lemma=\"in\">in </w><w type=\"DPS\" lemma=\"she\">her </w><w type=\"NN1\" lemma=\"time\">time</w><c type=\"PUN\">, </c><w type=\"VHD\" lemma=\"have\">had </w><w type=\"VBN\" lemma=\"be\">been </w><w type=\"AT0\" lemma=\"an\">an </w><w type=\"AJ0\" lemma=\"active\">active </w><w type=\"NN1\" lemma=\"member\">member </w><w type=\"PRF\" lemma=\"of\">of </w><w type=\"AT0\" lemma=\"an\">an </w><w type=\"NN1\" lemma=\"organisation\">organisation </w><w type=\"VVN-VVD\" lemma=\"call\">called </w><w type=\"AT0\" lemma=\"the\">the </w><w type=\"NN1\" lemma=\"noise\">Noise </w><w type=\"NN1\" lemma=\"reduction\">Reduction </w><w type=\"NN1\" lemma=\"society\">Society</w><c type=\"PUN\">, </c>")
```

I've got close to what I want using this:

```
library("stringr")

# Extract type
type <- str_extract_all(text, "<. type=\\\"(.*?)\\\"") %>%
    unlist()

#Extract word
word <- str_extract_all(text, ">(.*?)<\\/.>") %>%
    unlist()

#Convert to Data frame
df <- data.frame(
    type = type, 
    word = word)
```

The problem is that I only want the things that appear between `<w type = \"` and `\"` etc., not those characters themselves, so something like this (for the first two words):

```
df2 <- data.frame(type = c("NP0", "PUN"), word = c("Dorothy", ","))
```

Again, with the understanding that I should learn, say, the `XML` package for this type of data, can I get what I want with regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [look around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in order to extract only the strings *between*. I've also added `str_trim` in order to remove unwanted spaces around the words

```
data.frame(
  type = str_extract_all(text , '(?<=type=\\")(.*?)(?=\\")')[[1]],
  word = str_trim(str_extract_all(text , '(?<=\\">)(.*?)(?=<)')[[1]], side = "both")
)    

#       type         word
# 1      NP0      Dorothy
# 2      PUN            ,
# 3      PRP           in
# 4      DPS          her
# 5      NN1         time
# 6      PUN            ,
# 7      VHD          had
# 8      VBN         been
# 9      AT0           an
# 10     AJ0       active
# 11     NN1       member
# 12     PRF           of
# 13     AT0           an
# 14     NN1 organisation
# 15 VVN-VVD       called
# 16     AT0          the
# 17     NN1        Noise
# 18     NN1    Reduction
# 19     NN1      Society
# 20     PUN            ,
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. I do get a warning saying that `perl is deprecated. Please use regexp instead`. Seems to works fine getting rid of the `perl()`.

Comment: Yeah, I had a very old version of `stringr`. Edited.